# Django | Error al aplicar get_ _display en return del models.py

Tags: django, django-models

Al aplicar get_ *display (para que en vez de devolver 0 ó 1, devuelve "Batería, Otro" en el return me devuelve error, en cambio cuando lo utilizo (get* _display) en el template funciona sin ningún problema. ¿Qué hago mal?

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** models.py

```
class TypeConsumable(models.Model):
    CONSUMIBLE_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        ('0','Batería'),
        ('1','Otro'),
    )
    type_typeConsumable = models.CharField('TipoConsumible', max_length=1, choices=CONSUMIBLE_TYPE_CHOICE,null=True)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tipo Consumible'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tipos de Consumibles'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.get_type_typeConsumable_display)
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una función, por lo tanto se le olvido colocar los paréntesis -> ():

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.get_type_typeConsumable_display())
```

Comment: Gracias. Estaba acostumbrado a poner en el template ejemplo. {{ get_opcion_display }} por eso me estaba confundiendo. Gracias Piero Pajares.

Comment: De nada Julian !

Answer (score 1):

Como se menciono anteriormente el error esta en el magic method **str**, solo hace falta llamar el método `get_type_typeConsumable_display` como tal. Además a partir de Django 3.0 existe una nueva alternativa para definir enumeraciones para los campos de los modelos a través de las clases TextChoices, IntegerChoices y Choices [Documentación Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

**Nota.** Es importante notar que estas restricciones de valores a nivel de aplicación no crean constraints en la base de datos por lo cual tendrías que hacer estos constraints a mano, te agrego un link donde explica más al respecto. [Agregar constraint choices](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/22/djangos-field-choices-dont-constrain-your-data/)